# Run "passenger start" from within a shell script?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rvm, passenger

Basically, "passenger start" works fine from the terminal, but a simple script like "passenger start" doesn't work because it fails with:

```
*** Exception PhusionPassenger::UnknownError in PhusionPassenger::Rack::ApplicationSpawner (Could not find abstract-1.0.0 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)) (process 19278, thread #<Thread:0x7f16dbfaf368>):
```

Looks to me like it can't find the gems anymore. This seems to be a very common problem on Google, but I cannot find any simple answer. I do not want to monkey patch my rails application with something like this: http://blog.ninjahideout.com/posts/the-path-to-better-rvm-and-passenger-integration (which I couldn't actually get to work, anyway)

It seems unbelievable that there's not a simple way to handle this. Why is running passenger from a shell script any different from typing it by hand?

---

UPDATE: basically, I fixed it by not using passenger. Instead of using "passenger start" I now use "rails server" and it works fine. Now, obviously, this doesn't "solve" the issue I was having, but it's good enough for my development needs.

I'd also like to elaborate a bit on my setup, because I think I was a bit vague.

Basically, I had this script called start_rails.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /rails/app
passenger start
```

It didn't work, and I tried everything under the sun, including sourcing all of my bash files, and nothing worked. I changed it to:

```
#!/bin/bash
source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"
cd /rails/app
rails s
```

And now it works. I can run it from an upstart script:

```
start on started mysql
exec sudo -u ubuntu -i /home/ubuntu/bin/start_rails.sh
```

However, "passenger start" still doesn't work, never has, and I guess never will =P I still don't know why there's no way to run a shell script and tell it to "run it exactly as if I was typing it in manually" because simply typing "passenger start" does work. From a shell script, it doesn't. Oh well. Life goes on.

Comment: Is the script running from the same directory you're typing in your command? Try prepending your script with cd /path/to/application;

Comment: The world of a logged in user is different than that of a non-terminal user.  Log in via ssh and you get path, and colors and so on.  But when you are a non-terminal user, things are different.  Crontab tasks seem to run as a user, but in a non-terminal environment.  Capistrano tasks can also suffer the same fate.  The key line is in `.bashrc`, which is often called by `.bash_profile` having this part: `# If not running interactively, don't do anything
[ -z "$PS1" ] && return`  which says, if a person isn't seeing this don't do anything else.  Many hours have been spent understanding this.

Comment: Wow, I haven't tried it yet, but my bashrc file does include [ -z "$PS1" ] && return # If not running interactively, don't do anything. I bet that was the problem, lol! Thank you so much, tharrison!

Answer (score 1):

If you can run passenger by hand without problems you are in a good position right now :).
I guess there is some problem with environment variables that are set when you log in but not when the script is run. Try to add these two lines at the beginning of your script:

```
source ~/.bash_profile
source ~/.bashrc
```